# Invoking a Javascript function in a compiled script in Java's Script API

Tags: java, javascript

I have some code where I am successfully loading and compiling a script. This is working great. Next, though, I want to be able to call a function inside the compiled script. Unfortunately, I don't see any way to make a compiled script invokable.

```
Compilable compEngine = (Compilable)engine;
compiledScripts.put(filename, compEngine.compile(new InputStreamReader(in)));
compiledScripts.get(filename).eval();
//All works until this point. The compiled script does not seem to be invokable.
Invocable inv = (Invocable) compiledScripts.get(filename);
inv.invokeFunction("onLoad");
```

Is there a way to do this? If so, how? If not, how much of a performance hit is their generally when not compiling the script?

Comment: What library are you using here?  Rhino?

Comment: Rhino is the default Javascript Engine in Java, so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. It is actually a very simple change.

This line:

```
Invocable inv = (Invocable) compiledScripts.get(filename);
```

Needs to change  to:

```
Invocable inv = (Invocable) compiledScripts.get(filename).getEngine();
```

This returns the engine the compiled script is getting run in, thus letting us call functions from the compiled script.